# Chainlink - Job not being fulfilled

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, chainlink

I've been learning the Chainlink API and trying to build a simple contract that will make an external call to an API and charge the user based on the result of the request from the Oracle.

For example, "We will charge you $1 if the API results in `true` and $0.25 if it results in `false`"

I am running this on the Kovan Testnet, the contract is funded with LINK. The transaction is successful every time I run the "requestCompletedData" function. But the callback/fulfill function never gets ran. I've checked it in various ways.

For reference, it should result `completed == true` based on the data from the URL.

Here are the Contract Address and Job ID for Chainlink's Kovan test nodes: https://docs.chain.link/docs/decentralized-oracles-ethereum-mainnet/

```
// 
constructor() public {
        setPublicChainlinkToken();
        oracle = 0x2f90A6D021db21e1B2A077c5a37B3C7E75D15b7e;
        jobId = "6d914edc36e14d6c880c9c55bda5bc04";
        fee = 0.1 * 10 * 18; // 0.1 LINK
    }

    // Make Chainlink request
    function requestCompletedData() public returns (bytes32 requestId) {
        Chainlink.Request memory request = buildChainlinkRequest(jobId, address(this), this.fulfill.selector);
        
        // URL for request
        request.add("get", "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/4");
        
        // Path to the final needed data point in the JSON response
        request.add("path", "completed");
        
        return sendChainlinkRequestTo(oracle, request, fee);
    }

function fulfill(bytes32 _requestId, bool _completed) public recordChainlinkFulfillment(_requestId) {
        validateChainlinkCallback(_requestId);
        completed = _completed;
    }
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `validateChainlinkCallback(_requestId)` line in your `fulfill()` method and it will work.

```
function fulfill(bytes32 _requestId, bool _completed) public recordChainlinkFulfillment(_requestId) {
        completed = _completed;
    }
```

The `fulfill()` method already has the `recordChainlinkFulfillment` modifier which runs the same validation as the `validateChainlinkCallback(_requestId)` method anyway.

Reference: [ChainlinkClient source code](https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/blob/develop/evm-contracts/src/v0.6/ChainlinkClient.sol).